# how to view another language in notepd++ with a file containing some other language

Tags: notepad++

i have given encoding ad encoding in utf-8 but iam still not able to view the chinese language and that language has been viewed as square braces. please someone help me how can i view the chinese language in notepad++.i have a php file containing chinese language but it is not viewes as chinese and it has been viewed as square braces when opened in notepad++. please help me.i have given encoding ad encoding in utf-8 but iam still not able to view the chinese language.this is what i can describe about my problem. thanks

Comment: can you post that text here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about encoding and not programming

Answer (score 1):

Paste Your Text
**NotePad++ -> Encoding --> Convert to UTF-8**

Comment: already i have done that but it is not working.

Comment: Also - check your font - if you are using courier the default notepad++ font  - it doesn't have Chinese characters - I switched to Arial Unicode and my problem solved - http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Encodings_And_Character_Display#What_to_check_when_characters_display_in_an_unusable_way.3F